# Displaying correct data from models in django

Tags: python, django

I'm facing a rather weird problem in django. I'll try my best to explain it coherently.

What I need:

1. I have a page that displays 10 listings from a model called `Channel`.
2. Each of these listings will have links to their standalone pages that are generated using `get_absolute_url`

Clicking on these links will generate a new view that will display further details for that listing.

Now, the problem I face is that when this link is clicked it generates the new view correctly but it shows no data from the model `Channel`.

My model is as follows:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    identity = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/img/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.identity)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('channel', kwargs={'channel_url': str(self.identity)})
```

The views.py for this is:

```
def channel_final(request, channel_url):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    partner = Channel.objects.filter(identity__exact=channel_url)
    content_dict = {
        'part': partner,
    }
    return render_to_response('templates/channel-final.html', content_dict, context)
```

The generated links look like: `localhost:8000/channel/1`.

Urls.py

```
    url(r'^channel/(?P<channel_url>\w+)/$', views.channel_final, name='channel_partner'),
```

Comment: What's in your template that you want to show but isn't showing?

Comment: @Alex for example, i've used `{{ part.name }}` in my template, which should display that listings name from the model, correct? It doesn't show up in the view.

Comment: What about trying get() instead of filter? You may be getting a queryset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is in your view:

```
partner = Channel.objects.filter(identity__exact=channel_url)
```

here you get queryset of Channel instances and in template you want to get name ({{ part.name }}) from queryset, but it doesn`t have one. I think you need change filter to get:

```
partner = Channel.objects.get(identity__exact=channel_url)
```

Answer (score 3):

`filter` *always* gets a QuerySet, even though your criteria only matches one instance. A QuerySet is a list-like container, and so you'd need to iterate over it to get the actual objects which have the attributes you need to access.

But in fact you should be using `get` instead of `filter` in the view to only return a single object.